# Pyramid - Forms and number formatting/localization

Tags: python, forms, validation, localization, pyramid

I'm considering switching to Pyramid but I'm wondering on how to localize a form. How can I have a form that would accept/validate numbers in a locale specific format? (thousands and decimal separators, etc)

Django currently does this for me by using `localize=True` on fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pyramid project is known for it's excellent documentation, and there is a [Internationalization and Localization section](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/i18n.html) available.

Pyramid does not, however, dictate what form framework you use in your applications. Localization services themselves are generally deferred to [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/), including number and date formatting routines. You'd have to either tie these into your form framework of choice or find a framework that already ties into Babel for this work (I know of none but that doesn't say much).